# Division algebra over 2-adic fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, quaternions, division-algebras

Let $D$ be the quaternion division algebra and $O$ be a maximal $\mathbb{Z}$-order in $D$, say the Hurwitz quaternion integers. It can be proved that $D$ and $O$ split at odd primes, that is 
$$D\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}_p=Mat_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)\text{ and }O\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_p=Mat_2(\mathbb{Z}_p),$$ for all odd primes $p$. What are the structures of $D\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}_2$ and $O\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: IIRC the division algebras over $\Bbb{Q}_p$ are all cyclic, so there is no choice in the index two case. Not sure what happens when you tensor $O$. You can calculate the discriminant of that tensor product (should be the same), and see if it matches the known discriminant formula. If it does, then you know it's a maximal order. Given that the discriminant is the product of local discriminants it probably is a maximal order. [Reiner's book](http://www.amazon.com/Maximal-Orders-Mathematics-Irving-Reiner/dp/0198526733) covers a lot of very useful material.